# Error after upgrading to Jasper 5.5.0

Tags: jasper-reports

After upgrading the Jasper Version to 5.5.0, I am getting error while compiling the report from server/Jenkins. In my local machine it is working fine. Any idea what can be the reason. Below is the log:

```
[WARNING] POM for 'commons-logging:commons-logging:pom:99.0-does-not-exist:runtime' is invalid.

Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[INFO] [jasperreports:compile-reports {execution: default}]
[INFO] Compiling 29 report design files.
[INFO] Compiling report file: interfaceConfiguration\processConf.jrxml
[FATAL ERROR] org.codehaus.mojo.jasperreports.JasperReportsMojo#execute() caused a linkage error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) and may be out-of-date. Check the realms:
[FATAL ERROR] Plugin realm = app0.child-container[org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-2]
urls[0] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/org/codehaus/mojo/jasperreports-maven-plugin/1.0-beta-2/jasperreports-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-2.jar
urls[1] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/5.5.0/jasperreports-5.5.0.jar
urls[2] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
urls[3] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
urls[4] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.1/commons-collections-2.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/commons-digester/commons-digester/2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar
urls[6] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js2/itext-2.1.7.js2.jar
urls[7] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/jfree/jcommon/1.0.15/jcommon-1.0.15.jar
urls[8] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.12/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
urls[9] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.02/xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
urls[10] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/eclipse/jdtcore/3.1.0/jdtcore-3.1.0.jar
urls[11] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/org/codehaus/castor/castor/1.2/castor-1.2.jar
urls[12] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.1.4/jackson-core-2.1.4.jar
urls[13] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.1.4/jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar
urls[14] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.1.4/jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar
urls[15] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/jasperreports/jasperreports/1.2.0/jasperreports-1.2.0.jar
urls[16] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
urls[17] = file:/d:/maven/maven-2.0.9/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.5.3/plexus-compiler-api-1.5.3.jar
[FATAL ERROR] Container realm = plexus.core
urls[0] = file:/C:/APPS/DCSCM/tool/Maven2.2.1/lib/maven-2.2.1-uber.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream
javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream
    at net.sf.jasperreports.web.util.WebResourceHandlersExtensionRegistryFactory.<clinit>(WebResourceHandlersExtensionRegistryFactory.java:47)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:53)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:237)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:214)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:162)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:133)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:105)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.getExtensions(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:246)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.findBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getCachedBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:109)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:97)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment.getComponentBundles(ComponentsEnvironment.java:179)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.getSchemaLocations(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:84)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.configureParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:131)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.createParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:94)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1439)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1415)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:254)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:210)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:185)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:176)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:137)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:438)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jasperreports.JasperReportsMojo.compile(JasperReportsMojo.java:249)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jasperreports.JasperReportsMojo.execute(JasperReportsMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: I've a similar problem, but not exactly the same. Changed from 5.1.0 to 5.5.0. I've tried to delete the maven local repository, but this didn't solved anything. Have you tried?

Comment: Anyway, I think it's a compatibility problem between jasperreports-maven-plugin and latest jasper version...

Comment: I finally moved to 5.2.0 and now it is working fine.

Comment: I resolved compiling the reports at runtime and not using maven plugin.

Comment: Ok so you compile the report in Jenkins, right?

Comment: No, I compile at runtime in my application using JasperCompileManager.

Comment: ok, but that increases the compile time, right?

Comment: I tried only with a few small reports and I didn't even noticed the compile time. Anyway if you decide to compile at runtime you can compile the first time and keep the .jasper file for later calls, so you don't have to recompile again

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the servlet API as a plugin dependency.  For example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile-reports</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <!--note this must be repeated here to pick up correct xml validation -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```